# Simple Work and Energy Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, friction, work

A $40\,\mbox{kg}$ case is pushed across the floor at a constant speed of $1.5\,\mbox{m}/\mbox{s}$, when the pushing stops, the case slides a further distance of $1.2\mbox{m}$.

Calculate the work done per second to push the case at a steady speed of $1.5\,\mbox{m}/\mbox{s}$.

I used the formula $W= F \cdot x$.

Since  $F = ma$, and with constant velocity $a = 0$, wouldn't $F = 0$, so:
$$
W = 0 \cdot x = 0
$$

So would it take $0\,\mbox{J}$ of work?

I am really confused, as the formula $F = ma$ was taught to me in physics, yet $W = F\cdot x$ was given to me in engineering.

Comment: You are correct. Net force is equal to zero due to a balance between applied force and the force of friction. No work is being done. Getting the case to a speed of 1.5 m/s would require work however.

Comment: @KrisWalker The question is for work done _to push_, not total work of the system.

Comment: Ah, it seems I somehow overlooked that. Oops.

Comment: Kris your missing the point of the question. there is friction, so work is being done to move it at a constant speed

Comment: no work is being done on the object* But work is being done against friction.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use **work-energy relation**, which states that *net work done by all external forces* on a body is equal to *change in kinetic energy* of the body.

Here we can assume the force of friction to be constant $f$. Let the force applied be $F$. Then since it stops after application of $F$ at distance $d$, work done by friction $W_f = -fd$. This must equal change in kinetic energy, that is $\dfrac{-mv_o^2}{2}$ ($v_o = 1.5, \ m=40$). So you obtain f.
$$fd =\dfrac{mv_o^2}{2}$$

Now since the body was earlier moving with constant velocity, you have $F=f$.

**Edit**

We had to calculate work done per second to push the block. This is simply the power imparted by $F$ to body and is equal to $Fv_o$.

This is because $P = \dfrac{dW}{dt} = \dfrac{Fdx}{dt}$ (since $F$ and $dx$ are parallel). So we get $P = Fv_o$.

Comment: If F you mean the frictional force, then your answer should be -FV as The forces are equal but opposite in magnitude so F=-f

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a constant force of friction
When the pushing stops, it is traveling with some velocity. Thus the only force acting on it is friction.The equation of motion for the block in terms of energy is

$\frac{1}{2} mv^2 +Fd = 0$

Aka as an object moves with a velocity v,  negative work is being done by the force of friction slowing it down. when it moves a distance d, the kinetic energy is zero

$\frac{1}{2} (40)(1.5)^2 +F(1.2) = 0$

The magnitude of the force of friction is

F= - $\frac{1}{2} (40)(1.5)^2 \frac{1}{1.2}$

for an object moving at a constant speed, the applied force must be equal  and opposite to the frictional force. Thus the work I would have to do against the force of friction to move it at a constant speed is

w = $\int (-F)dx$

If dx = Vdt
where v is speed

$\frac{dw}{dt}=  (-F)\frac{dx}{dt}$

$\frac{dw}{dt}= (-F) v $

$\frac{dw}{dt}= (-F) (1.5) $

= $ \frac{1}{2} (40)(1.5)^3 \frac{1}{1.2} $

You notice that the rate at which  work is being done against friction is velocity dependant.

Answer (score 0):

$F=ma$ is true for the net force. The *net* work done on the box is zero. The person that is pushing the box is doing some work by the force that is applied through his hands but the force of friction is doing the same amount of work in the opposite direction. You know those two are the same because the net force is zero (constant velocity).